# How to check if all the strings matching in a file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am getting input from an existing program consisting of strings separated by a pipe (`|`) character:

```
$ echo "$list_of_nodes"
NODE-BB-4|NODE-AA-1|DUMMY
```

Now I need to check whether each of them is present in a separate file:

```
$ cat file
NODE-BB-4 1.1.1.1
NODE-AA-1 2.2.2.2
```

- **case-1**

  should pass when the input string is `"NODE-BB-4|NODE-AA-1"` as both of them are present in the file,
- **case-2**

  when the input string is `"NODE-BB-4|NODE-AA-1|DUMMY"`, should fail as `"DUMMY"` is not present in the file.

This is how I thought of doing this but seems definitely not the best idea:

```
$ echo "$list_of_nodes" |tr '|' '\n' |while read line;
> do grep -q "$line" foo ;
> echo $? ;
> done|awk '{s=s+$0} END{print s}' |awk '$1>0{print "Fail"}'
Fail
```

Here I am looping with each pattern to grep and store the return code and then checking if it is grater then 0 or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
list_of_nodes="NODE-BB-4|NODE-AA-1|DUMMY"
awk -v nodes_str="$list_of_nodes" \
'BEGIN{ len = split(nodes_str, arr, "|") }{ nodes[$1] }
 END{ for (i=1; i<=len; i++) if (!(arr[i] in nodes)) print "Fail" }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is function for such check

```
check() {
   FileToCheck="$1"

   #cycle will check all patterns.
   #if one of patterns will fail, function will stop immediately with Return Code 1
   while read p; do
     grep "${p}" ${FileToCheck} >/dev/null || { echo "${p} not found in ${FileToCheck}"; return 1; }
   done < <( tr '|' '\n' )  #modify input for cycle via tr(replace | by newlines)
   #if we running here, all checks are Okay, Return Code 0.
   return 0
}
```

Example files:

```
$ cat patterns 
NODE-BB-4|NODE-AA-1|DUMMY

$ cat file
NODE-BB-4 1.1.1.1
NODE-AA-1 2.2.2.2
```

Here is an example of using:

```
cat patterns | check file
echo $?
```

The result:

```
DUMMY not found in file
1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"
p="NODE-BB-4|NODE-AA-1|DUMMY"
patterns=${p//|/ }

fileMatchesAllNames () {
  file=$1
  if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]
  then
    echo "$file"
  else
    shift
    pattern=$1
    shift
    grep -q "$pattern" "$file" && fileMatchesAllNames "$file" $@
  fi
}

test -f "$file" && fileMatchesAllNames "$file" $patterns
```

The function is called with a bunch of patterns to search for, takes the first one, as long as there is one, tests for it and removes it with `shift` for the next call.

`grep -q` is eagerly returning as soon as finding a match (implies -m1).

If the file matches all patterns, its name is printed. Else the program terminates silently as soon as a pattern can't be matched.

It's modified from a former solution to a SO question, where a list of files should be checked and can be shortened a bit, since the filename needn't be passed to the function again and again.

#!/bin/bash

```
file="$1"
p="NODE-BB-4|NODE-AA-1|DUMMY"
patterns=${p//|/ }

fileMatchesAllNames () {
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]
  then
    echo "$file"
  else
    pattern=$1
    shift
    grep -q "$pattern" "$file" && fileMatchesAllNames $@
  fi
}

test -f "$file" && fileMatchesAllNames $patterns
```

Note, that the patterns are not allowed to contain white space, in order for the script to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                           

pattern="NODE-BB-4\|NODE-AA-1\|DUMMY"
words=3  # Number of patterns in $pattern
if (($(grep -o "$pattern" inputfile.txt | sort -u | wc -l) < $words)); then                                  
    echo "FAIL: Not all patterns found in input file"                                                                                
else                                                                                          
    echo "SUCCESS: All patterns found in input file"                                                                             
fi
```

This uses the piped commands:

```
grep -o "NODE-BB-4\|NODE-AA-1\|DUMMY" inputfile.txt | sort -u | wc -l
```

that will return the number of unique patterns found in `inputfile.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

When the nodes are given as the first column in your file, you can use `grep`.
I want to use your `tr` approach, written differently.

```
tr '|' '\n' <<< "${list_of_nodes}"
```

You can make the output look like a file with process substitution

```
<(tr '|' '\n' <<< "${list_of_nodes}"
```

When you want to check these with the first fields of your file, then cut the file.

```
cut -d' ' -f1 file
```

You can use the outoput for another process substition and use a `grep` (option x: complete match).

```
grep -xvf <(cut -d' ' -f1 file) <(tr '|' '\n' <<< "${list_of_nodes}")
```

Now you can replace output with `sed`.

```
sed -r 's/.+/FAIL: &/'
```

Parts together:

```
grep -xvf <(cut -d' ' -f1 file) <(tr '|' '\n' <<< "${list_of_nodes}") |
   sed 's/.+/FAIL/'
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {n=split($0,x,"|"); 
              for(i=1;i<=n;i++) nodes[x[i]]; 
              next} 
 $1 in nodes {delete nodes[$1]} 
         END {for(k in nodes) print "fail: " k}'  <(echo "$list_of_nodes") file

fail: DUMMY
```

removes all the seen nodes and print the remaining ones with failure tag.

Or, another quick way to compare and output the missing node

```
$ comm -23 <(tr '|' '\n' <<< "$list_of_nodes" | sort) <(cut -d' ' -f1 file | sort)
DUMMY
```

you can condition on the output size to fail or succeed, but perhaps not ignoring what is missing is useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
list_of_nodes='NODE-BB-4|NODE-AA-1|DUMMY'
sed $(echo "$list_of_nodes" | \
sed "s/|/\/!bA;\//g;s/^/ :B;\$bC;N;bB;:C;\//;s/$/\/!bA;d;:A;s\/.*\/fail\/ file/")
```

---

First create a sed command from list_of_nodes with sed

```
:B;$bC;N;bB;:C;/NODE-BB-4/!bA;/NODE-AA-1/!bA;/DUMMY/!bA;d;:A;s/.*/fail/ file
```

And execute it

```
sed $(...)
```